# xamarin, visual studio 2015 component element is not declared

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, components

im new at mobile programming and c#, i had started working in a company as intern, company wanted me to learn xamarin and perform a small side app for their ERP project. Anyway i was going well but i have to make a navigation drawer menu i check examples in net and downloaded source code to see how projects builded but when i try to run my own app and downloaded project i get following error 
axml file of a project that i have downloaded

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:text="Hey slide from left or right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
<!-- The left navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/leftListView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#D2D2D2"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2" />
<!-- The right navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rightListView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#D2D2D2"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

getting

> The 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout' element is not
>   declared. DrawerLayoutTutorial    C:\Users\cankut\Desktop\Xamarin27Done\DrawerLayoutTutorial\DrawerLayoutTutorial\Resources\layout\Main.axml 2

Also when i tried to debug/run program i get following errors

> Unzipping failed. Please download
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r28.zip
>   and extract it to the
>   C:\Users\cankut\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.2.1.0\content
>   directory.    DrawerLayoutTutorial    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.target

But i have get component android.support.v4, android support designer.
i had also try to install components in nuget packages but still no luck, i also check web for my problem but no luck seem my problem far different also my android support repository is uptodate, thanks for your answers.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this is because Xamarin was not able to download the zips compleately

refer to http://duanenewman.net/blog/post/2016/03/16/Xamarin-Build-Errors-Please-Install-Package-XamarinAndroidSupportv4.aspx

als try removing the files at the location and rebuild it would download it for you or manualy download from the url specified and add to zips

Comment: the link to the post is broken. you may need to give detail to make the answer clear.